# Intermittent failure of Wifi on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm on an [Asus TUF A15](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/For-Gaming/TUF-Gaming/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-A15/) running Ubuntu 20.04. The Wifi occasionally disconnects. It will show that it's connected to the router, but the network manager tray icon will just show a question mark and I'll have no connection. I can't replicate the cause--it just disconnects intermittently, and there's no action I can take to reconnect it. Restarting seems to help, although eventually it does disconnect again.

I tried googling the problem but I just saw a bunch of very specific conversations about it on random websites that I didn't understand. Is anyone familiar with this error or issue in general who can point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I examined the `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager` output and found two warnings, both from earlier (while it was still working):

```
[1618494465.1485] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
[1618494466.4222] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
```

Output of `iwconfig wlp3s0` with working internet:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Fios-7X4CA"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 18:78:D4:0E:06:60   
          Bit Rate=234 Mb/s   Tx-Power=23 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0
```

Output of `iwconfig wlp3s0` after updating channel to 161:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Fios-7X4CA"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: 18:78:D4:0E:06:60   
          Bit Rate=292.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:11   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Your assumption is probably incorrect. Linux doesn't usually have "driver breaks other driiver" problems.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks--I'll keep an eye on those logs as the problem occurs again and update the question based on the output. I'll also monitor my actions and see if there is some sort of reproducibility that I can point to.

Comment: The command I gave will show all the NetworkManager logs for the current boot. You should read the `man` page (`man journalctl` in this case) before executing a command given to you by a stranger on the internet.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, and true. I examined the output and posted it above.

Comment: Log entries, even "warnings" of a working system have no relevance to a failing system.

Comment: @waltinator In that case I don't know how to diagnose it. It's still doing something that a working system shouldn't be doing.

Comment: You're confused. You start with a wireless problem. Then articulate a video driver problem. Then you articulate a link command for your ethernet. Which is it? Edit your question and show me `iwconfig wlp3s0`.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the feedback. You're definitely correct, I've had some confusion about what could be causing the issue. I've updated the question with the output of `iwconfig wlp3so`. (I should note, though, that I used that command while the internet was up. I'll post again with the output when it disconnects.)

Comment: You're using the 5Ghz wireless network. What is the 5Ghz channel set to in your router? What channels are available there? Do you have, or can you get, `Wifi Analyzer` app on your smartphone, and review what channels are being used in the 5Ghz frequencies?

Comment: @heynnema It [looks like](https://imgur.com/a/LxD6vut) it's channel 149.

Comment: @heynnema Available channels listed [here](https://imgur.com/a/dKZ2GoV).

Comment: Do `iwlist wlp3s0 freq` to see what your wireless card can do, then look for the highest channel that's also available in your router. Set the router to the highest channel that your wireless card can do, reconnect, and show me the new `iwconfig wlp3s0`. You can also test by connecting to the 2.4Ghz band, and show me the new `iwconfig wlp3s0`.

Comment: @heynnema Updated question with the ouput of `iwconfig wlp3s0` on the 161 channel. I don't know how to select the 2.4GHz, they switched it to an automatic selection some time ago...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123066/discussion-between-heynnema-and-yehuda).

Comment: @heynnema Sounds good, I've responded there.

Answer (score 0):

Your current wireless connection is forced to channel 161 in the 5Ghz band. At "Signal level=-72 dBm", the signal may be too weak to maintain a reliable connection.

Your router is set such that it auto-selects the 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz band for you.

We'll force it to channel 11 in the 2.4Ghz band and see if that helps.

Open your wireless settings for the network **Fios-7X4CA** and change the BSSID from blank, to 18:78:D4:0E:06:62, like so (you can use the pop-down arrow)... and click the **Apply** button...

[image]

(re)connect to the wireless network and recheck connectivity.

Then show me `iwconfig wlp3s0`

If the network is more reliable, you'll have to change the Verizon router such that the 2.4Ghz band has a different name, and then connect to that in the future (or just leave the settings as above).

Comment: First off, thanks for the help. Question--does this answer suggest that I might not be able to regularly utilize the 5G? What would be the reason for that, if that's the case? I have a Chromebook that I am able to use with no issues further away from the router, is this simply an Ubuntu or a RTL8822CE issue?

Comment: @Yehuda 5Ghz doesn't travel as far as 2.4Ghz, and can be more prone to physical barriers than 2.4Ghz. We'll try forcing you to 2.4Ghz, review the iwconfig, and see if that's more reliable. For THIS PARTICULAR COMPUTER, in its current location, 2.4Ghz may prove to be more reliable. Question... is your Verizon wireless router/modem located physically high, or is it sitting on the floor, behind other equipment?

Comment: @Yehuda Is the Chromebook connecting to 5Ghz or 2.4Ghz?

Comment: @Yehuda Are you in a house, or apartment?

Comment: I'm in an apartment. The router is on the floor in the bedroom; even in the room next to the bedroom, I've suffered disconnection. The router and equipment is all sitting amonst each other. I reset the 5G to automatic and set the 2.4G to channel 11, and set the BSSID as instructed. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PFqspf5THb/) is the output of `iwconfig wlp3s0` following those changes. Re: the Chromebook, because the Wifi is set to auto-switch between 2.4G and 5G as necessary (I think it's called a "self organizing network") , I assume it connects to both fluidly.

Comment: @Yehuda It's still connecting to the 5Ghz band, so the Signal Level is still way too low. In the wifi setup panel, is 18:78:D4:0E:06:62 one of the choices in the pop-down selector for BSSID? Did you disconnect and then reconnect after the change to the wifi settings? Regarding the router... ANY router will work better up higher... not on the floor. You can't assume that the Chromebook connects to either band, unless you know that the hardware supports both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, or until you look at "connected devices" from the router admin page.

Comment: 18:78:D4:0E:06:62 is available in the dropdown menu. Regarding reconnecting, do you mean restarting the router, or my computer's connection? I'll also see about moving the router.... I've also been poking around in the system logs, and noticed the following message repeating over and over: `zone serial <number> unchanged. zone may fail to transfer to slaves.` Might this be relevant?

Comment: @Yehuda I don't recognize that error message out of context. Can you answer my questions from my last comment?

Comment: Answered them above, thanks. To your other point, I actually just checked the Chromebook in the router network status, and it looks like it's only connected on 2.4G...

Comment: @Yehuda reconnecting... either turn off/on wifi... and monitor iwconfig "Frequency:5.805 GHz" for a 2.4Ghz number. Then show me a fresh iwconfig.

Comment: It [appears to be](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kkhtS3PFHy/) at 2.4G now....

Comment: The 2.4Ghz connection doesn't appear to be any stronger than the 5Ghz connection. There may be an issue with the wifi hardware, or the driver. Do you have an external USB wifi dongle we can try? Show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I do. I might have to reformat it, it's flashed to the Ubuntu ISO right now.

Comment: @Yehuda No, not a USB flash drive, but a USB wifi dongle. Get the modem/router off of the floor and see if the signal gets any stronger in iwconfig.

Comment: [Here's](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vRywyqcJt6/) the output from that. I also found [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/guvpac/asus_tuf_a15_wifi/) about the ASUS A15 just now....

Comment: The iwconfig looks better, but the error rate is too high. Is the router off of the floor now? Show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: [Here's](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Tn5f33YY3G/) the output from that (I sanitized it as well).

Comment: @Yehuda In the router, is the 2.4Ghz channel set to AUTO, or a specific channel? Do you have a smartphone? Can you install `Wifi Analyzer` on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123320/discussion-between-heynnema-and-yehuda).